# Node library for TDS 7.0 (SQL Server 7)

Tags: node.js, sql-server, tds

Has anyone successfully connected to Sequel Server 7 (TDS 7.0) with node.js?  How did you do it?

I've tried tedious and node-mssql, but the lowest version of the TDS protocol that they use is 7.1.  I need to access a SQL Server 7 database, which only speaks TDS 7.0.  (Ancient, I know . . .)

The only library I've found that looks like it works is node-tds, but it was abandoned long ago, so getting help with it is pretty unlikely.  I get `TypeError: invalid_argument` when trying to connect, and there is no documentation on the `connect()` function.  :(

Comment: SQL Server 7 end of live was in 2011, you should upgrade your database server. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/end-of-support-for-sql-server-7-0/

Comment: @Piotr It's a legacy system.  We've moved on to a completely different business setup, but sometimes need to look up historical data from the rust bucket.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it to work, but it wasn't as simple as installing a single node module that contained all the necessary pieces.  I ended up using `node-odbc`.  You just have to install and configure a couple pre-requisites (unixODBC and FreeTDS).  This was always a pain when I'd had to do it in the past, but this time around I found some instructions for installing both via Homebrew.  It's probably just as easy with your package manager of choice. Configuring the setup was a little bit of work, but manageable by following the instruction guide at [freetds.org](https://freetds.org).